# How to run android integration tests against different server environment using Dagger2

Tags: android, integration-testing, dagger-2

I've android integration test that I want to run against different server environments like *Production*, *Staging*, etc.

```
public final class IntegrationTest {
  private MyClient client;

  @Inject
  private Environment env;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
     // set up environment depending on Environment injected above.

     // Android specific stuff...

  }

  @Test
  public void testServerResponse() throws Exception {
    ...
    client.getToken(request);
    ...
  }
}
```

I somehow feel I should use Dagger2 to inject my modules like ProdModule, StagingModule at runtime to be able to do so. But I'm having hard time on how I should go about that using Dagger2.

Can someone please help me:

1. Designing these modules
2. How to bind these modules at run time
3. Any other help that I'll need to achieve the same (TestRunner modification?)

Someone pointed to me that it is easy to setup such a thing using GuiceBerry for Java integration testing, but I'm looking for solution in android.

Comment: You don't need different modules if only the URL is changing, just supply a different URL.

Comment: Well in my case modules perform a lot of setup work so solution you've proposed is not feasbile.